# Co-authorship in exchange for paying conference fee

Tags: publications, ethics, authorship

My BSc dissertation has recently been accepted for publication in the proceedings of a small conference. My supervisor has co-author credit as his assistance was naturally instrumental.

While I'm been working a career, my supervisor has **very kindly** been shopping the paper around for publication and has finally landed a hit here. He's been leading the charge all the way towards publication.

We were just discussing the presentation, and he sent me a file marked "Final". It contained my original paper, **now with a third person as co-author.**

I asked him who this person is; I assumed that they were perhaps another professor or lecturer, or maybe another student who'd contributed something new. The response I got was:

**"He's the guy paying the conference fee. That's sadly how research works in real life."**

I was never informed of this third person when the paper was submitted, and it was submitted with **their name included.**

My understanding is that they have contributed nothing further to the paper.

How do I stand in this situation ethically?
Should I withdraw?
Is this normal?

Comment: This is absolutely not “how research works in real life”. However it’s typical of corrupt and cynical people to delude themselves into thinking that everyone is also corrupt and cynical like them. It’s the only way they can live with themselves.

Comment: I have been involved in my share of drama over authorship (not by choice, these kinds of things just inevitably happen), but this has to be one of the most outrageous reasons I've ever heard to add someone to a paper. Having said that I personally wouldn't take any actions against your advisor until you are safely being advised by someone else and I wouldn't take any actions that would hurt your own career, like withdrawing. I'm sorry this happened to you.

Comment: I wonder what this third party can even do with authorship on a paper they didn't contribute to... even if they use this to get grant funding, it's not like this sets them up to actually be able to do any further research. What a strange story.

Comment: "*Is this normal?*"  Is the paper in the field of engineering?  I suspect this practice is "accepted" in some countries.

Comment: How much is the conference fee? Don't ask the professor first, ask the conference, then the professor.

Comment: The title of this question is very misleading based on the content of the question. Nobody **accepted money** for co-authorship, he only paid the publication expenses, he didn't bribe anybody.

Comment: @Andrew: There is seriously something wrong going on here. What if that third co-author is actually a fraudster? Even if you use purely selfish reasoning, not withdrawing can also hurt your career if you knew but did not disclose fraudulent authorship.

Comment: Are you sure that guy is paying the fee himself, or could he be the guy getting money for the conference fee? The latter might be a professor/lecturer; but still seen as only the person getting the funding. I'm not saying that it makes the situation any better.

Comment: _my supervisor has **very kindly** been shopping the paper around for publication_ - From what you've told us, I don't see how you can distinguish this being kindness as being self-serving, since your supervisor and some unknown person are also co-authors.  In fact, if you have a non-academic career, I don't see what a publication does for you at all.

Comment: I'm aiming to re-enter a career in academia so there is value for me.

Comment: @Andrew: It may be that the 3rd party is only _able_ to use funds for this purpose if they're included as an author.

Comment: @JackAidley I see... so maybe the advisor has a friend with extra funding, who is willing to foot the bill as a favor, but had to be added as an author to use the funding. That's very far from anything I've experienced in physics, but I do find it plausible since I can't see any way the third author would benefit enough to pay money to be made an author on an undergrad thesis; if this is a favor it makes more sense. While I think it's very unusual and sketchy, I still think "just go along with it and give the talk" is in the OP's interest.

Comment: Reading between the lines, it sounds like the advisor is essentially out of funding and embarrassed enough to not be upfront about it. To me that provides a lens where I can at least understand why people are acting this way... if the advisor is trying to do the best for the student by enabling them to attend the conference, without having access to funds themselves for whatever reason.

Comment: As a side note for your future career: you should try to send the papers yourself when you are the first author to avoid similar problems. This may not always be practical, and you may run into conflicts though. I had quite a lot of friends who were waiting months+ for their supervisor to "accept the paper" (**especially** when they were not listed as authors...) and when I asked them why they do not simply send it by themselves - they did not want to get into conflicts. Life sucks sometimes.

Comment: What field? In mine the marginal benefit for the third person is so low ... but might be different in CS

Comment: "He's the guy paying the conference fee...": With the same logic, we would need to add all of the tax payers as co-authors to publicly funded papers since *they pay the bills*

Comment: Customs for who is listed as an author vary considerably by field.

Comment: If this third author is "paying the conference fee", who is actually attending the conference? Will you present your own paper at the conference @ConnieMnemonic? Will your advisor attend?

Answer (score 53):

Personally, you are fine. The actions weren't yours. You are being used, I'm afraid, and your professor has an ethical problem. "Sadly" is exactly right and I hope they are wrong, even in a narrow sense, but it isn't a widespread practice.

But if your advisor is willing to do such things for a bit of money, I'd suggest you bite your tongue so that you don't bring down the wrath of the powers that be on your own head.

What is real life is that you have to occasionally deal with unethical people and sometimes have to just protect yourself to advance your career. Sorry you got stuck in this swamp.

Comment: You forgot: "Run, don't walk."

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, indeed. I wanted to add that once you break free you might consider complaining, but from a safe distance.

Answer (score 38):

I can’t advise you on what to do, since you are the person who will be living with the consequences of any action you decide to take. It is your decision to make how to deal with the situation.

I’ll just say this: if I heard a year or two from now that one of the people applying to my department’s graduate program was the person who famously exposed the money-for-authorship scandal at University of X by writing that viral blog post in late August 2021, in which they cited the immortal line “*He's the guy paying the conference fee. That's sadly how research works in real life*” from their adviser’s email and quoted the full unredacted email, **you would be number 1 on my list of people I’d recommend to my department to accept.**<sup>*</sup> And you would be number 1 on my list of people I’d want to mentor, and people I’d want to help have a successful academic career.

This is *not* normal. It’s corruption, pure and simple, and would not be considered remotely acceptable in any part of academia I’m familiar with.

<sup>Well, assuming you had decent potential to succeed in a mathematics graduate program, of course.</sup>

Comment: This answer should be improved by noting that the people that would recommend OP as number 1 (as Dan would) are an exception. Most people would recommend someone that is known for his **academic** achievements, not someone who wants to be known for discrediting and exposing his collaborators for personal gain.

Comment: @user000001 that sounds like an [opinion](https://youtu.be/1vBesOFURek) rather than a fact. I reject both your framing of the class of people I belong to as people who don’t care about academic achievement, and your characterization of that class as small.

Comment: (And I reject your framing of exposing the corruption as being “for personal gain”. It is no more appropriate to say that than to say that _not_ exposing the corruption, as advocated in another answer, would be for personal gain.)

Comment: Middle, slightly cynical view: some employers will probably look at a non-anonymous whistleblower as a risk because "if they'll throw their former employer under the bus, maybe they'll do it here...". And it's not necessarily just the unethical employers. They might be afraid that OP might decide something that's actually within ethical bounds is whisteblowing-worthy (not saying OP would, but a potential employer might worry this). So I do think that whistleblowing publicly (vs. anonymously) is a career risk because you are now a risk to an future employer (in their mind).

Comment: @bob good point. To balance what you said, there is also risk with the route of not taking any action. If the corrupt authorship-for-conference-fee scheme is later found out (because someone else decided to blow the whistle, say), OP’s name could end up tainted by their silence, which would seen by some as complicitness. So, unfortunately life has all kinds of risks, and it’s not always possible to avoid career risk altogether.

Comment: interesting on the OP side we have the cynical professor, and here we have the exact opposite of it.

Comment: @encryptoferia there are plenty of non-cynical professors. There isn’t anything unusual about my attitude.

Answer (score 29):

Should you withdraw? No.

Should you have been consulted before submission? Yes, but sadly it's common for senior academics not to properly consult undergraduates and other junior scientists about submissions for publication.

Is this ethical? In some fields, crediting the people who got the grant money to do the science as authors is common practice regardless of their further involvement. The argument is that getting the money takes time and effort and the science can't be done without it. Getting published is a necessary part of science and publication fees can be significant. I would count this as dubious rather than clearly unethical, but - and I can't emphasise this enough - it depends on field. Some fields have very narrow views of authorship, others have very broad views. Reactions from people outside your field usually throw more heat than light.

Finally, I note your framing is incorrect. Your supervisor did not accept money for authorship; they agreed to add the author in return for them paying something for the paper's publication. Your supervisor isn't getting any money from this, and will get minimal benefit from this extra paper, especially compared to how much you benefit.

Comment: Which fields are those in which "crediting the people who got the grant money to do the science as authors is common practice regardless of their further involvement". From my admittedly limited academic experience, that's what the "acknowledgements" section is for.

Comment: @Fizz It's common in parts of the Life Sciences, and probably elsewhere. In this case Acknowledgements are usually used to acknowledge the source of the funding, rather than the person who applied for the funding.

Comment: I'm guessing it's for that reason that some publications in that field more recently require a statement of what work each author contributed...

Comment: @FIzz: That's part of it, yeah. Authorship is a totally outdated concept, unfit for purpose in most fields of science today, and should be dropped in favour of a better system IMO. But unless it is we'll be stuck with silly arguments over what authorship actually means.

Comment: I would disagree with your statement of "Your supervisor did not accept money for authorship". We don't know whether the third party simply whipped our their "credit card" to pay the fee, or handed the supervisor "cash" (or a PO, etc.). The effect is the same. Fees were required. the supervisor (and I assume the OP) did not have enough liquidity to pay the fees." The supervisor approached a third party to make the fee payment. The supervisor accepted the value of the fees so the supervisor did, in fact, accept money, whether it was in the form of a purchase order, credit, or cash.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think this is the right read of the situation. As far as I can tell, the person benefitting the most here, at the end of the day, is the OP. Even though the situation seems unusual to me from the point of view of physics, I sympathize with an advisor lacking their own funds doing whatever it takes to enable their student to attend a conference.

Comment: @CGCampbell: It doesn't make any difference whether it was a credit card, cash, or a direct payment. The point is that the money is going to serve a purpose that is part of the supervisor's _work_, not their personal finances. The supervisor is no richer after the transaction than they were before. The common practice in academia of conflating the supervisor having money with the supervisor controlling money as part of their work isn't helping here.

Comment: @JackAidley a bribe in which the money is directed towards the receiver’s professional goals instead of going into their own pocket is still a bribe. I believe this is a well-established principle in the context of criminal law, (although defendants regularly try to make the same argument you are making, usually without success). Here we are talking academic ethics, which is a slightly different thing (I think it’s unlikely this scheme would be of interest to any criminal prosecutors), but the principle remains the same. So OP’s framing seems correct to me, if perhaps lacking in nuance.

Comment: About the “in some fields the funder of the research gets authorship” argument: it’s one thing to say that it’s not unusual for the person funding the lab and staff salary that _enabled the research to be carried out_ to be a coauthor. That seems a bit shady, but I agree it’s common enough in life sciences that there is not much reason for outrage. But being added as a coauthor for paying the _conference fee_ after the research _was already completed_ is a very different thing. That is not “getting the grant money to do the science”. As I said, it’s corrupt, and indefensible IMO.

Comment: @DanRomik I agree it's on much shakier ground but publishing and disseminating the results of a study is not an optional part of science; without it you're playing in a lab not doing science. As I said above, I'd rather see authorship dropped as a concept unfit for purpose, but until it is I see little value in being overly precious over unimportant infractions.

Comment: I think another component of a bribe is that the third party is paying in order to *further their own interests* in some way. It's really not clear to me what the third party gains from being an author, it could essentially be a favor to the advisor (ie, third party is willing to pay for the conference fee that advisor can't afford, but needs to be an author to use grant funds). Still sketchy, but I think it's worth pointing out there is a plausible reading of the situation that isn't a bribe. I agree with Jack that the weight put on authorship creates problems like this.

Comment: @JackAidley as much as one can argue about authorship, it's pretty obvious from the definition that paying for an event is not authorship of a publication. Neither is paying for publication. It's not a problem of the authorship concept, it's absurdly misusing it that's the problem. any other concept would suffer the same fate if there is a way to "invest" without repercussions into fame and academic credits.

Comment: @FrankHopkins That was the intention of my comment, actually. I was considering what if... what if someone like Einstein, or any other world renowned scientist could not afford to publish, and accepted moneys to do so at the cost of authorship. Now a third party has become famous (or more likely infamous) as the result of nothing _except having a bankroll_

Comment: +1 Reactions from people outside your field usually throw more heat than light.

Answer (score 20):

1. Is this normal?  No, and it should not be.
2. Should I withdraw? No.  Presumably the results are still valid.
3. How do I stand in this situation ethically? You yourself have done nothing wrong: it is your supervisor that is being unethical.

This is NOT how science is done these days, and thankfully this kind of bribery is rare. There isn’t much you can do yourself except carefully consider if you want to continue collaborating with this person.

Comment: +1 for a clear and concise analysis of the situation. Probably the best answer so far.

Answer (score 7):

Adding a co-author purely because they paid for something is definitely inconsistent with academic standards. The policies of journals and professional societies make that clear and can be cited. What you can do is **add a grant number in the acknowledgments**, at the end of text. That way the sponsor can list your work as part of what has been accomplished with the funding, without being a co-author on the paper. That would be the proper solution; everyone will get credit for what they contributed, and if you insist you will prevail.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, selling authorships for a conference publication is like selling your soul for a hamburger. Nobody needs a conference publication that bad, though on the plus side, it's a conference so most likely nobody will ever care.

Second, yeah, it's unethical, and it's not how research works. "A friend" of mine once had a boss who had a habit of including government technical monitors as conf paper authors, which apparently did butter some of them up, but there were occasions when "the friend" could tell that the technical monitor felt pretty skeevy that this boss would even offer. My friend recalls one getting pretty irritated about it (they have some pretty severe quid pro quo policies). I should note this boss was from a country where this kind of thing is par for the course and which regularly appears in the news for corruption scandals (if I said what it was you'd go "ahaa"). His lax sense of ethics on a more serious matter eventually got him massively and expensively sued, like on a "forget about retiring" level.

I'm not sure if I'd call them out on it or not. I guess I'd have to know more about the paper and the circumstances of the work, particularly the funding and the background. It really sounds like a strange situation, that this guy just comes out of the blue and wants an authorship. Again, for a conference paper? Most conferences, to get a paper in, all you have to do is write something vaguely related to the field and pay the registration fee. It seems to me like there's more behind the scenes that we're not aware of. If it was a journal, I'd go nuclear on it, but conferences are pretty loosey-goosey about a lot of stuff. Like, it's not at all uncommon for professors to just randomly stick new grad students on conf papers just because they're in the research group.

Answer (score 1):

You are in an abusive relationship. Supervisor and student is an interpersonal relationship, and just like with any interpersonal relationship, there are cases of abuse. Sadly, academia is full of such abusive situations.

**Don't walk, run! As with any abusive relationship, it's not going to get better no matter what you do. It will only get worse.**

You are in a state of denial:

> While I'm been working a career, my supervisor has **very kindly** been
> shopping the paper around for publication

It sounds like you kind of try to find something good in your abuser in order to suppress your gut feeling, but your gut feeling is right. This is not common in the academic fields that I am aware of.

If your supervisor strains your relationship with you in that manner, he or she doesn't care about you. Your supervisor knows it's unethical, your supervisor probably has a guess what opinion you have of him, so obviously he has no long-term interest in you. **He won't help you and throw you under the bus whenever convenient. Don't count on him ever for your career.**

*Honestly, the third author could just as much have been a desperate guy looking for a publication and paying your supervisor directly. Don't believe anything that guy says.*

You should not withdraw, because it's your work, and nobody will hold a grad student accountable. However, **Don't walk, run** and get away from that guy as quickly as you can.

**As with any abusive relationship, it's not going to get better no matter what you do. It will only get worse.**

Answer (score -4):

## Contact the journal editor (confidentially)

What you describe sounds very problematic, even after you tried to discuss the situation with your advisor. It sounds like you have already tried asking your advisor to clarify the situation, but his response was evasive, in that he did not confirm what (if anything) the 3rd party contributed **in the capacity of co-author**. Hence, as you say:

> My understanding is that they have contributed nothing further to the paper.

You should try to ascertain whether that is the case by analysing the manuscript very carefully. Read it word for word, and check whether there is anything in there that you do not recognise as coming from yourself or from your advisor.

Of course, there is a (small) **possibility** that the advisor **did** involve the 3rd party in the process of making contributions that you believed to have come solely from your advisor, but if that were the case, your advisor should have mentioned to you that he had been involving a 3rd party **at the time**.

Personally, my view is that a person on the author list must be able to present on and answer detailed questions about all aspects (albeit allowing for **some** division of labour or specialisation, provided that everyone **understands** what is going on) of the work encapsulated in the paper (including exploratory work, investigative stages, and methodology), and **it sounds like this 3rd party cannot do that**.

**So, my advice would be to contact the journal editor (confidentially)** and explain the situation, forwarding all relevant correspondence and drafts in your possession. The editor, who should be familiar with what constitutes authorship and who should have the authority to ask tough questions, will then be able to investigate the issue properly and come to a determination of whether your advisor acted appropriately (based on the information you have given, the answer is probably "no", but it is difficult to be sure without seeing the details and asking tough questions of all parties concerned).

Of course, once you have taken the step of going to the editor, you (and your 'co-authors') will probably have to abide by whatever decision he/she makes. Depending on the details of the case, possible outcomes include:

- the editor retracts the article due to academic malpractice; or
- the editor publishes the article with just two authors (you and your advisor), and asks you to mention the 3rd party to the 'Acknowledgements' section instead; or
- the editor is satisfied with the explanations given by your advisor and publishes the article with all three parties as authors.

You should be prepared for the possibility that this will result in your "burning bridges" with your advisor. But to be honest, that **might** be a good thing (**if** it turns out that your advisor were corrupt); better to cut your losses now than to be tainted by corruption and blighted by toxic working relationships.

Comment: Oh wow, I think this is a really bad idea. If you *were* going to contact the journal editor, I would definitely make sure the email you sent to the editor had a clear request for an action. In practice, the editor's job is not to mediate conflicts between co-authors and I think this email will make the OP look unprofessional. Finally I get the sense that the OP doesn't know the full story. I would not kick the hornets nest of burning bridges with a *current* academic supervisor without knowing all the facts. It's not at all clear to me that the advisor is corrupt.

Comment: What journal editor? The question is about a conference paper

Comment: @Andrew   Granted: the student has next to 0 leverage on the supervisor, else there would not be this conflict, and the outcome of this is *possibly* one less presentation for a student who has done nothing wrong, but I doubt the conference organizers would allow as a policy this kind of academic dishonesty on the part of some authors and co-authors.